# How to store SMS message to SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite

I want to store the messages into `SQLite` database when they receive. I know I have to use `BroadcastReceiver` to do this. But I don't know how to do this. Is it possible to store incoming sms into database when `onReceive()` is called?
Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can store the messages into sqlite database.

This is the onReceive() method code :-

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //—get the SMS message passed in—
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String messages = "";
    if (bundle != null) {
        //—retrieve the SMS message received—
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[smsExtra.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
            //take out content from sms
            String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

            messages += "SMS from" + address + ":\n";
            messages += body + "\n";

            putSmsToDatabase(sms, context);
        }
        //—display the new SMS message—
        Toast.makeText(context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void putSmsToDatabase(SmsMessage sms, Context context) {
    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);

    SQLiteDatabase db = dataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    // Create SMS row
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("address", sms.getOriginatingAddress().toString());
    values.put("date", mydate);
    values.put("body", sms.getMessageBody().toString());
    // values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ );
    // values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus() );
    // values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX );
    // values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN );

    db.insert("datatable", null, values);

    db.close();
}
```

and the full tutorial is :-

http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87

Hope this help you :)

Comment: i have used `ContentResolver` to get Inbox message from a specific number also. I need to store this in order to maintain a customer maintenance Application which contains more fields. I need to insert them in Database too.

Comment: You are right but he wants to save the messages to database so I suggest him the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You donot need to save it in database,you can directly get it from

```
Uri myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(myMessage, new String[] { "_id", "address", "date",
                "body", "read" }, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            smsLogsIncoming = new HashSet<SmsLogData>();
            smsLogsOutGoing = new HashSet<SmsLogData>();
           // timeLastChecked = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
            simNumber = tm.getLine1Number();
            do {
                date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
```

Comment: i have already used `ContentResolver` and displayed messages on `ListView`. This time I don't want to show that in anything. I have to add some more fields to sms data and store it in separate table.